Git Graph in VS-Code: How do I code new branches and connect them?
I have to write a code for a git graph on VS Code that has to look exactly like this:

I can get to the main graph until „included documentation“ but as soon as the first branch should be placed, it looks totally different than it should. I have no idea what commands I should use. Whenever I tried to merge, the branches end up on a wrong place and don‘t look like the picture. Here are my (latest) exact commands suggested by Chat GPT.
First branch:
git init
echo "#Main project" > main.py
git add main.py
git commit -m "create main.py"
git commit --allow-empty -m "first draft"

Now this is where it all goes wrong: Chat GPT-tells me to add the multiplication, but instead of different branches I still get one branch with another branch on a completely wrong place:
git checkout -b add_multiplication
echo "def multiply(a, b): return a * b" > multiply.py
git add multiply.py
git commit -m "adding multiplication"
git commit --allow-empty -m "included documentation"
git commit --allow-empty -m "continue on the main branch"
git checkout main
git merge add_multiplication -m "merge add_multiplication"
git checkout add_multiplication
git commit --allow-empty -m "add exception of dividing by 0"
git checkout main
git checkout -b add_addition 
echo "def add(a, b): return a + b" > add.py
git add add.py
git commit -m "adding addition" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "refining addition" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "reformulating addition" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "finalizing"
git checkout main 
git merge add_addition -m "merge add_addition" 
git checkout main 
git checkout -b reformulate_addition
echo "def subtract(a, b): return a - b" \> subtract.py 
git add subtract.py 
git commit -m "reformulating addition" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "fail, use previous version again"
git checkout main 
git merge reformulate_addition -m "merge reformulate_addition"
git commit --allow-empty -m "add visualization" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "try to resolve merge conflicts" 
git commit --allow-empty -m "resolve merge conflict"

After these commands the graph looks like this, which is wrong:

I need the git-commands for the branches and how to connect them with the main branch (or at least for one branch, so I get how to do the others). I also don't understand how to cross over the branches like in the picture.

In the expected graph, you have multiple branches coming together but in your code, it seems that you are only doing fast-forward merges. Make sure that both branches have commits before merging them if you don't want fast-forward merges (or use --no-ff). Also, it seems like reformulate_addition is never merged in the expected image.

I think you might want to look into what merging actually does.
